# toggle select option based on checked is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have html form, here i want to show dropdown option based on  checkbox is checked or un-checked.

If checkbox is checked then i want to append india to end.
If checkbox is un-checked then i want to remove india in the dropdown option.

```js
var jsonData = {'status':'success', 'text':'Locations found', 'data':[{"name":"Afghanistan","code":"af"},
      {"name":"Albania","code":"al"},
      {"name":"Algeria","code":"dz"}]};
      console.log(jsonData);
  $(function(){
   var options = '';
   $('#newcountry').change(function(event) {
    if(this.checked){

    jsonData.data.push({'name':'India'});
   for(i=0; i<jsonData.data.length; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + jsonData.data[i].code + '">' + jsonData.data[i].name + '</option>';
         } 
          
    $('#country').append(options);

    }else{

     for(i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + jsonData[i].code + '">' + jsonData[i].name + '</option>';
     

         } 
        $('#country').append(options);  
    }
    
   });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
            <div>
                <input id="newcountry" type="checkbox">
                    <select id="country" name="country">
                        <option value="">
                            --Select value--
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </input>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to separate this out a bit to get you to whichever section you are struggling with. I'm pretty rusty on jQuery so I've converted this over to regular JS, but hopefully it is still clear.

- the `renderList` function shows building options and sending them to innerHTML on the parent element.
- and in the `init` function the checkbox handler works on altering the list to be rendered

A couple of places that look to be an issue in your initial example, there is no initial load state (the dropdown is blank until you check the box), and you are only ever appending to your selectbox (you would need to remove options before resetting)

```js
const jsonData = '{"status":"success","text":"Locations found","data":[{"name":"Afghanistan","code":"af"},{"name":"Albania","code":"al"},{"name":"Algeria","code":"dz"}]}';

const buildOption = (option) => `<option value="${option.code}">${option.name}</option>`;

const renderList = (list, parentElement) => {
  const options = list.map(item => buildOption(item)).join('');
  parentElement.innerHTML = options;
}

const init = (jsonData) => {
  const obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  const selectBox = document.querySelector("#country");
  const checkBox = document.querySelector("#newcountry");
  let list = obj.data;

  checkBox.addEventListener("change", event => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      list.push({
        name: "India",
        code: "code"
      });
      return renderList(list, selectBox);
    }

    // this section finds the added 'India' element and then slices it out of the list.
    const idx = list.findIndex(i => i.name === "India");
    if (idx > -1) {
      list = [...list.slice(0, idx), ...list.slice(idx + 1)];
    }
    renderList(list, selectBox);
  });
  
  renderList(list, selectBox);
};
init(jsonData);
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div>
    <input id="newcountry" type="checkbox">
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="">
        --Select value--
      </option>
    </select>
    </input>
  </div>
</form>
```